# How can I solve thie ODE with boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

How can I solve this:

$\frac{d^4G}{dx^4} = \delta(x-\bar{x}) $ Boundary conditions: $G(0) = G'(0) = G''(1) = G'''(1) = 0$

I tried:

Let $G(x) = A_1x^3+A_2x^2+A_3x+A_4$ if  $ x < \bar{x}$ and $G(x) = B_1x^3+B_2x^2+B_3x+B_4 $ if   $x>\bar{x}$

then using the boundary conditions I get all the coefficients are zero, but when I put this in wolframalpha it gives me an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Did you apply the jump-condition at $\overline{x}$ correctly? With $G_+ = a_+x^3 + \ldots$ and $G_- = a_-x^3 + \ldots$ it should give you: $6(a_+-a_-)=1$. Doing this (plus continuity) I get $$G(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{c}\frac{3\overline{x}^2x-\overline{x}^3}{6} & x\geq \overline{x}\\ \frac{3\overline{x}x^2-x^3}{6} & x< \overline{x}\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: btw the $x=1$ boundary conditions only apply for the $B$'s and the $x=0$ boundary conditions only apply for the $a$'s.

Comment: Thank a lot, I applied to both A's and B's. I'll do it again :)